# Only few DLLS are listed by WMI C# of a process

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to iterate through the processes of a machine and list all data files that process is using.. I am not getting all the files that process is using getting only..

c:\windows\system32\wow64win.dll,

c:\windows\system32\wow64cpu.dll,

c:\windows\system32\wow64.dll,

c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll.

Why other dlls are not listed by WMI here... if process explorer shows all the correct files.

```
 using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where ProcessId = 25364"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process Name:",
                    mo.Properties["Name"].Value);
                    // Get processes having this File open
                    var b = mo.GetRelated("CIM_DataFile");
                    if (b.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Stop");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you search by .dll extension in the process?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: wow64 is the "windows on windows" emulator that supports running 32-bit code on a 64-bit version of Windows.  In other words, you got the 64-bit view of the process so can't see the 32-bit DLLs that were loaded.  You changed a project setting, the kind of detail you must never omit from a question.  Consider Process.Modules as an alternative.  You already knew that, the kind of detail you must never omit from a question.

Comment: is there any way i can find all the dlls of a process through WMI.. I dont want to use Process Class.

Comment: Are all the dlls running under the process except above 4 dlls?

Comment: Yes all the dlls are running under the process.. Process manager is also showing all dlls including these 4..

Comment: @HansPassant Just wondering, but is there a way to get the 32b DLLs by way of WMI alone? I tried the (documented) `__ProviderArchitecture=32` and `__RequiredArchitecture=true` but only got a `SWbemServicesEx: provider load failure` error. My use-case scenario is WSH-hosted JScript, without .Net or PowerShell. Thanks for any pointers or insight.